# trouble with Kivy Buttons and Variables

Tags: python, button, kivy

I am trying to make a health system, i have an image of a gem and when i click the "increase Humanity" button another gem will appear to the right of it.
i also have a "decrease Humanity" button that is suppose to remove a gem.

i use a variable for the range of a for loop.
for eg,

```
current_Humanity_value = 1



self.Humanity_Up = Button(text='Increase Humanity',
                          pos_hint={'center_x': 0.25, 'center_y': 0.65},
                          size_hint=(0.1, 0.1))

self.Humanity_Up.bind(on_release=self.increase_current_Humanity_value)


def increase_current_Humanity_value(self, button):
    global current_Humanity_value

    current_Humanity_value += 1

    x = 0.1
    y = 0.1
    for i in range(current_Humanity_value):
        x += 0.05
        self.add_widget(Image(source='./Images/Humanity_gem.png',
                              pos_hint={'center_x': x,
                                        'center_y': y}))
```

Then as i said two buttons will increase or decrease the current_Humanity_value variable.

When i click the button to increase health, another gem will appear.
When i click the decrease button the value of current_Humanity_value will go down, but the gem image will not update.

so the code can add an image, but it does not update anything exactly.

i think i need to take the 'for loop' out of the button code, but then how do i update the current_Humanity_value?

while i am still learning kivy i have choosen to not use the .kv file until i understand how everything works.

so i am looking for a way to make a button increase/decrease a variable and update images accordingly.

I am finding kivy quite difficult to understand because there doesn't seem to be a while loop?
I have spent the last 6 moths learning python for 'pc' and everything made logical sense, the code is read top to bottom, inside the while loop; but i find with kivy that i don't really know where to put code.

what is the build function for?
why do some youtubers put everything inside it and others just leave it blank and build the code inside the **init** function?

Comment: Kivy is not difficult to understand and in general, UI programs doesn't have any loop. I think your problem here is more realted to how you write your code. For Kivy you'd better use a .kv file and a .py file it will be really easier for you to understand everything. You could easly do something then using a GridLayout in your kv file where you add an image on it when the button is pressed.

Comment: You say that your problem is with the "decrease Humanity", but you only show us the "increase Humanity" code that works.

Comment: the decrease is exactly the same, but with -= and not +=